# Adding comments on request

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, model

I have two fields that I want to save as a comment in the request: the first one would be a reference point and the second would be the client's address type (residential or commercial), but the code I found can save only one comment per request and I you would need to save two fields as a comment in the request.

I would like to know how can I save two fields as comment in the request and not just one?

I will leave the code I have of which only saves one comment in the request, which is contained in the Observer.php file.

```
 if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Consultor do atendimento: ' . $oscOrderData['comments']);
        $order->save();
    }
```

**Note: `comments` is the `id` of the field to be saved.**

**First field to comment:**

```
<label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Referência: ') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
   <input class="input-text required-entry" id="comments" name="comments" title="<?php echo $this->__('Reference point') ?>" />
</div>
```

**Second field for comment:**

```
<select class="required-entry" id="comments" name="comments" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="validate-select onestep required-entry">
   <option>Select</option>
       <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
       <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you paste the html part that includes the comment input fields?

Comment: @AlexDinca I updated the question with the `HTML` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of the problem is that both your inputs have the same name but without the array modifier. In other words, the `name` attribute must be `name="comments[]"` to send both values as an array. Otherwise only the last one would be available in the `post` parameters.

Here's how your inputs must look like:

```
<input class="input-text required-entry" id="comments_1" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Reference point') ?>" />

<select class="required-entry" id="comments_2" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="validate-select onestep required-entry">
   <option>Select</option>
       <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
       <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

Now, the second thing you need to do is loop through the `comments` array in your Observer and add each of them to the order history

```
if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

    // Force array type
    if(!is_array($oscOrderData['comments']))
        $oscOrderData['comments'] = array($oscOrderData['comments']);

    foreach($oscOrderData['comments'] as $comment) {
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Consultor do atendimento: ' . $comment);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: It worked, but it's saving an extra field in the comment: it's saving the reference point and the address type correctly, and is also saving a field written `Array`.

Comment: What could be done to address this issue of saving a written field array?

Comment: looking in the source of the page, how many fields with `name="comments[]"` do you have?

Comment: I have only two fields, which in the case are the ones that are described in the question.

Comment: I found the problem, it was in a duplicate code in the same Observer.php